# Spell Corrector in C

Tags: performance, c, embedded, natural-language-processing

I recently stumbled across [this article on how to write a spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), and figured I'd try to have a go at it in C (mainly because the link at the end of the page for the C code is broken).

Here is what I would like reviewed:

- **Accuracy**: What can I do to make the program output a more accurate prediction of what it thinks the correct word should be?
- **Speed**:  Are there any improvements that could be made to improve runtime speeds?
- **Refinement**:  In what ways could I shorten my code down a bit?

---

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE_DICT 235886

char *dictionary = "/usr/share/dict/words";

const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

char *strtolower(char *word)
{
    for (char *s = word; *s; ++s) *s = tolower(*s);
    return word;
}

ENTRY *find(char *word)
{
    return hsearch((ENTRY){.key = word}, FIND);
}

int update(char *word)
{
    ENTRY *e = find(word);

    if (!e) return 0;

    e->data++;
    return 1;
}

int readFile(const char* fileName, ENTRY dict)
{
    int fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) return 0;

    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(dictionary, &sb)) return 0;
    char *result = strdup(mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0));
    if (result != MAP_FAILED)
    {
        char *w = NULL;
        char *delimiter = "\n";
        char *word = strtok(result, delimiter);
        while(word)
        {
            w = strtolower(strdup(word));

            if (!update(w))
            {
                dict.key  = w;
                dict.data = 0;
                hsearch(dict, ENTER);
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }

        close(fd);

        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

char *substr(char *str, size_t offset, size_t limit)
{
    char *new_str;
    size_t str_size = strlen(str);

    if ((limit > str_size) || ((offset + limit) > str_size) || (str_size < 1) || (limit == 0)) return NULL;

    new_str = malloc(limit+1);
    if (!new_str) return NULL;

    strncpy(new_str, str+offset, limit);
    *(new_str + limit) = '\0';

    return new_str;
}

char *concat(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    if (!str1) {
        str1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
        *str1 = '\0';
    }

    if (!str2) {
        str2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
        *str2 = '\0';
    }

    str1 = realloc(str1, strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    return strcat(str1, str2);
}

int deletion(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);

    for (; i < word_len; i++)
    {
        array[i + start_idx] = concat(substr(word, 0, i), substr(word, i+1, word_len-(i+1)));
    }
    return i;
}

int transposition(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);

    for (; i < word_len-1; i++)
    {
        array[i + start_idx] = concat(concat(substr(word, 0, i), substr(word, i+1, 1)), concat(substr(word, i, 1), substr(word, i+2, word_len-(i+2))));
    }
    return i;
}

int alteration(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int k = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);
    char c[2] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < word_len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet); ++j, ++k)
        {
            c[0] = alphabet[j];
            array[start_idx + k] = concat(concat(substr(word, 0, i), (char *) &c), substr(word, i+1, word_len - (i+1)));
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int insertion(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int k = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);
    char c[2] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i <= word_len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet); ++j, ++k)
        {
            c[0] = alphabet[j];
            array[start_idx + k] = concat(concat(substr(word, 0, i), (char *) &c), substr(word, i, word_len - i));
        }
    }
    return k;
}

size_t edits1_rows(char *word)
{
    size_t size = strlen(word);

    return (size)                + // deletion
    (size - 1)                   + // transposition
    (size * sizeof(alphabet))    + // alteration
    (size + 1) * sizeof(alphabet); // insertion
}

char **edits1(char *word)
{
    int next_idx;
    char **array = malloc(edits1_rows(word) * sizeof(char *));

    if (!array) return NULL;

    next_idx  = deletion(word, array, 0);
    next_idx += transposition(word, array, next_idx);
    next_idx += alteration(word, array, next_idx);
    insertion(word, array, next_idx);

    return array;
}

int array_exist(char **array, int rows, char *word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        if (!strcmp(array[i], word)) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char **known_edits2(char **array, int rows, int *e2_rows)
{
    size_t e1_rows = 0;
    int res_size = 0;
    char **res = NULL, **e1 = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        e1      = edits1(array[i]);
        e1_rows = edits1_rows(array[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < e1_rows; j++)
        {
            if (find(e1[j]) && !array_exist(res, res_size, e1[j]))
            {
                res = realloc(res, sizeof(char *) * (res_size + 1));
                res[res_size++] = e1[j];
            }
        }
    }

    *e2_rows = res_size;

    return res;
}

char *max(char **array, int rows)
{
    char *max_word = NULL;
    int max_size = 0;
    ENTRY *e;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        e = find(array[i]);
        if (e && ((int) e->data > max_size))
        {
            max_size = (int) e->data;
            max_word = e->key;
        }
    }

    return max_word;
}

void array_cleanup(char **array, int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
}

char *correct(char *word)
{
    char **e1 = NULL;
    char **e2 = NULL;
    char *e1_word = NULL;
    char *e2_word = NULL;
    char *res_word = word;
    int e1_rows = 0;
    char e2_rows = 0;

    if (find(word)) return word;

    e1_rows = (unsigned)edits1_rows(word);
    if (e1_rows)
    {
        e1 = edits1(word);
        e1_word = max(e1, e1_rows);

        if (e1_word)
        {
            array_cleanup(e1, e1_rows);
            free(e1);
            return e1_word;
        }
    }

    e2 = known_edits2(e1, e1_rows, (int*)&e2_rows);
    if (e2_rows)
    {
        e2_word = max(e2, e2_rows);
        if (e2_word)
            res_word = e2_word;
    }

    array_cleanup(e1, e1_rows);
    array_cleanup(e2, e2_rows);

    free(e1);
    free(e2);

    return res_word;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        puts("Usage: ./check <word>");
        return 1;
    }

    ENTRY dict = {};
    hcreate(SIZE_DICT);

    if (!readFile(dictionary, dict)) return -1;

    char *corrected_word = correct(argv[argc - 1]);
    puts(corrected_word);
}
```

#### Test run:

As you can see, the accuracy is somewhat low.  The runtime speeds are faster than the original Python program in the post above, but I feel could still be improved upon.

> ```
> time ./check miror
> miro
>
> real  0m0.118s
> user  0m0.092s
> sys   0m0.014s
> ```

Comment: To be clear: It _works_, but you'd like to increase the accuracy, right?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Correct

Comment: add a little comment in your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Didn't work for me

First off, I ran your program but it didn't ever find any word.  I suspect the problem was in the function `max`:

```
    if (e && ((int) e->data > max_size))
```

I didn't see anywhere in the program where `data` was ever incremented, except if you had a duplicate word in the dictionary.  My dictionary had no duplicate words.  Perhaps yours had duplicate words such as `Miro` and `miro`.  I changed the code to just return the first word in the array and it did start to work.  Although it seems like a waste to find all possible words just to return the first one.  It would be nice if the words in the dictionary were scored in some fashion and the highest scored word would be returned (for example, words with common letters could score higher than ones with uncommon letters).  You could do this by initializing `data` to some function like this:

```
    dict.data = score_word(w);
```

### Messy concatenation

The way you build new strings is very messy.  First of all, the function `concat()` has a couple of problems:

1. Doesn't check return value of `malloc` and `realloc`.
2. If `str2` is NULL, there is a memory leak.

Beyond that, between `concat()` and `substr()`, you end up allocating, reallocating, and freeing many temporary strings.  It would be simpler and even faster to:

1. Allocate one string the length of the final string.  You know this length because you are either deleting, modifying, or inserting into the original string.
2. Copy the relevant parts of the string into that final string.

Here is a rewrite of your concatenation functions, which doubled the speed of your program:

```
static void *checked_malloc(int len)
{
    void *ret = malloc(len);

    if (ret == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Takes a part of the source string and appends it to the destination string.
 *
 * @param     dst       Destination string to append to.
 * @param     dstLen    Current length of the destination string.  This will
 *                      be updated with the new length after appending.
 * @param     src       Source string.
 * @param     srcBegin  Starting index in the source string to copy from.
 * @param     len       Length of portion to copy.
 */
static void append(char *dst, int *dstLen, const char *src, int srcBegin,
        int len)
{
    if (len > 0) {
        memcpy(&dst[*dstLen], &src[srcBegin], len);
        *dstLen += len;
    }
    dst[*dstLen] = 0;
}

int deletion(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);

    for (; i < word_len; i++)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        array[i+start_idx] = checked_malloc(word_len);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, 0, i);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, i+1, word_len-(i+1));
    }
    return i;
}

int transposition(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);

    for (; i < word_len-1; i++)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        array[i+start_idx] = checked_malloc(word_len+1);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, 0,   i);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, i+1, 1);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, i,   1);
        append(array[i+start_idx], &pos, word, i+2, word_len-(i+2));
    }
    return i;
}

int alteration(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int k = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);
    char c[2] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < word_len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++j, ++k)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            c[0] = alphabet[j];
            array[k+start_idx] = checked_malloc(word_len+1);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, word, 0, i);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, c   , 0, 1);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, word, i+1, word_len-(i+1));
        }
    }
    return k;
}

int insertion(char *word, char **array, int start_idx)
{
    int k = 0;
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);
    char c[2] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i <= word_len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++j, ++k)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            c[0] = alphabet[j];
            array[k+start_idx] = checked_malloc(word_len+2);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, word, 0, i);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, c   , 0, 1);
            append(array[k+start_idx], &pos, word, i, word_len-i);
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

### Reallocation scheme

In `known_edits2()`, you realloc your array every time you add a new string to it.  This will take \$O(n^2)\$ time.  I suggest doubling the size of the array each time to avoid slowing things down.

Here is a rewrite of the reallocation scheme:

```
char **known_edits2(char **array, int rows, int *e2_rows)
{
    size_t e1_rows = 0;
    int res_size = 0;
    int res_max  = 0;
    char **res = NULL;
    char **e1  = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        e1      = edits1(array[i]);
        e1_rows = edits1_rows(array[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < e1_rows; j++)
        {
            if (find(e1[j]) && !array_exist(res, res_size, e1[j]))
            {
                if (res_size >= res_max) {
                    // First time, allocate 50 entries.  After that, double
                    // the size of the array.
                    if (res_max == 0)
                        res_max = 50;
                    else
                        res_max *= 2;
                }
                res = checked_realloc(res, sizeof(char *) * res_max);
                res[res_size++] = e1[j];
            }
        }
    }

    *e2_rows = res_size;

    return res;
}
```

### max()

`max()` is a poor name for a function.  At first I couldn't understand why you were taking the maximum of an array and an int, until I realized that you wrote a function called `max()` that didn't just return the maximum of two values.

### Memory leaks

After reading your concatenation code again, I see a lot of memory leaks.  All of your functions allocate space for new strings, but you never free your temporary strings.  For example:

```
    array[i + start_idx] = concat(substr(word, 0, i), substr(word, i+1, word_len-(i+1)));
```

Here, each `substr` call allocates a string.  The first string will eventually end up in the array but the second string is leaked.

### Minor bug

After running your program again, I found that there was a small problem with  this loop:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet); ++j, ++k)
    {
        c[0] = alphabet[j];
        // ...
    }
```

`alphabet` is a string with a terminating null character, so `sizeof(alphabet)` is going to include that null character.  As a result, on the last iteration of the loop, `c[0]` will be the null character, and you will concatenate an empty string instead of single character.  This results in a modification where you delete a character instead of altering or inserting.  It doesn't cause any serious problems but in my rewrite I defined `ALPHABET_SIZE` to be `(sizeof(alphabet)-1)`.

### Code

I made some other changes as well.  The full code can be found [here at Github](https://github.com/Jsdemonsim/Stackoverflow/blob/master/spell/spell.c).

Comment: Replacing my code with your code causes a segmentation fault to occur within the `find()` function.

Comment: @syb0rg It's probably because you need to replace `sizeof(alphabet)` everywhere with `ALPHABET_SIZE`.  I included a link to the full source code because there may be other changes that I made that I forgot to mention.

Comment: Ahh, yes I forgot to change it in an area.  Using your code from Github just to make sure we're on the same page, there is no longer any output now?

Comment: @syb0rg Maybe because I changed the name of the dictionary file.

Comment: No, that wasn't it; but it was close.  Turns out I had an internal problem with my dictionary somehow... but I got it fixed and it works now!  Any more suggestions on how to improve accuracy?  It still is quite inaccurate.

Comment: @syb0rg Well, right now it returns the first match, so it prioritizes deletions then transpositions then alterations then insertions.  It would be best if you had a dictionary where each word had a frequency count associated with it.  So more frequent words could be scored higher than infrequent words.  [You could start by using a frequency list like this one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists).